# MySQL. Не сохраняется результат вычисления возраста в столбец

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с ФИО и датой рождения. Требуется вычислить возраст. Делаю запрос в MySQL:

```
 SELECT
  `name`, 
  `date`,
  (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-YEAR(`date`))-(RIGHT(CURRENT_DATE,5)<RIGHT(`date`,5)
  ) AS `age`
FROM `date`;
```

Вычисление работает, столбец заполняется, но после обновления страницы все вычисления пропадают. Я понимаю, что запрос всего лишь проводит вычисления, но вычисление не фиксируется. Я как понимаю нужно запрос вложить в подзапрос, но не понимаю как это осуществить в моем случае. Помогите, пожалуйста.
[image: после]
[image: до]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сохранить вычисления в таблицу под наименованием `date`? Может бы так:

```
UPDATE `date` SET `age` = (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - YEAR(`date`)) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_DATE, 5) < RIGHT(`date`, 5));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Приходил к этому варианту, но вставлял оператор SELECT после знака "=" и получал 1093 ошибку. И не совсем понимаю почему. Можете объяснить логику? По идее мне нужно взять при помощи SELECT получившееся значение с этой формулы и поместить его в столбец age.

Comment: Ошибка 1093. В MySQL запрещено изменять данные и одновременно делать выборку из той же таблицы в подзапросе.